# I'm not able to work with sticky header and angular material items at the same time

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

So my problem is that I've created logic for sticky header and I've used mat-card component and it doesn't work with that. My sticky header logic looks like that:

1. Part of the header.html:

```
<div class="bee-row bee-row-2" (scroll)="onscroll()" [ngClass]="navbarfixed?'fixed':'nofixed'">
    <div class="bee-row-content">
        <div class="bee-col bee-col-1 bee-col-w3">
            <div class="bee-block bee-block-1 bee-image">
                <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active"><img alt="" class="bee-center bee-autowidth" src="/assets/img/LogoMakr-49eOqp.png"
                    style="max-width:300px;" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Logic inside header.ts

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onscroll() {
    if(window.scrollY > 100)
    {
      this.navbarfixed = true;
    } else {
      this.navbarfixed = false;
    }
  }
```

3. And there styles for that one:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    top: 0px;
}

.nofixed {
    position: static;
    transition: 0.2 linear;
    top: -50px;
}
```

I've added a mat-card component to one of the pages and when I try to scroll down, the header doesn't cover this component:

[image]

*Don't look on how fields are styled there, I haven't finished yet :)

*Does anyone know how to solve that?*
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: did you try to add a `z-index` to `.fixed` (e.g. `z-index: 9999`)?

Comment: yes, that solves the issue, thanks!